# How to find name of OU for an account

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-organizations

Hi I am using boto3 and I am attempting to get OU name for each account in my organization.

Can you advise?

Here is what I have tried so far:

1. I am listing accounts in organization using paginator.
2. I am able to get account ID, ARN, Join time etc.

I checked documentation and I found out

1. DescribeOraniazational-unit
2. List-organizational-units-for-parent

This methods are usefull, but I do not know OU id....

I am looking for something that will accept account ID and return the name of OU for it.

Does something like this exists? If not any ideas for alternative way of getting OU name for each of accounts in my organization?

Answer (score 0):

Can you do the following?

- [list-organizational-units-for-parent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/organizations/list-organizational-units-for-parent.html) on root. Now you have all the OUs
- For each OU, then [list-accounts-for-parent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/organizations/list-accounts-for-parent.html)

And then you will know the OU for every account.

This method is obviously not convenient if you want the OU of just one AWS account, but you said you wanted "to get OU name for each account in my organization"

Comment: Yes, that is a great advice, thank you. I just finished coding exactly what you advised.

Two questions/problems that come into my mind with this approach:

1. This approach is most likely going to be not efficient (in case of many accounts and OUs)
2. If I list-ogranizational-units-for-parent on root, and there are sub OUs in the organization (OU inside of OU), will I still be able to get them with this logic?

Comment: Actually I noticed now, one difference with my approach comparing to yours. 
In my code, instead of doing list-organizationa-units-for-parent on root I did list_children. Will the expected result  be the same? (sorry for another comment I could not edit previous one after 5 minutes)

Comment: The concern about nested OUs is not valid anymore. I have fixed it with the recursion. Everything seems to be working fine now. 

Thank you Seth.